# Cannot set Gateway in NetworkManager on Ubuntu

Tags: networking, ubuntu

I have several network interfaces and am setting them up via NetworkManager. When setting method to `manually` in `IPv4` tab the save Button is greyed out as soon as I enter a Gateway into the `Gateway` row. This only occurs for certain interfaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if the `never-default` option is set. This option is not mirrored in the GUI afaik although NetworkManager is intended for graphical desktop environments.

You can try adding the gateway via command line tool:

```
~$ nmcli connection edit nameOfConnection
> goto ipv4
> set gateway
enter 'gateway' value: 192.0.2.1
> save
```

Now nmcli should complain after validating the entry.

```
[…] gateway not compatible to »never-default«
```

Set this option to false and save should work

```
> set never-default
enter 'never-default' value: false
> save
```